# Grails unit test using grailsApplication

Tags: unit-testing, grails

I have a controller that on the save method calls a thread to retrieve some files. The thread has start() in a domain that has this line-

```
RetrievalThread retrievalThread = grailsApplication.mainContext.getBean ('retrievalThread').
```

In my unit test I tried this and it worked(I'll keep the other lines omitted that have no bearing right now). Without this line an error occurs saying can't get mainContext on null object,talking about grailsApplication. .

```
Def mainContext = Mock(ApplicationContext)
MainContext.getBean(_) >>{ name ->
return new MockRetrievalThread()}
```

The mock thread doesn't do anything.

This test runs fine but, any test after this fail with a null pointer exception  with no real information. Looks like a bunch of background grails stuff. Is there a way to clean this up or use something better than what I'm using?

Comment: I have encountered this issue where grails\grailsApplication not being injected properly when using regular tests,running the entire app through integration test solves this.are you using integration test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure there's a way to clean this up in a `tearDown`, but I think there is a better way.

1.) I would use DI rather than going through `grailsApplication.mainContext.getBean`; is there a reason you are doing it this way?

```
class MyController {
    def retrievalThread

    getFiles() {
        return [files: retrievalThread.getFiles(params.id)]
    }
}
```

2.a.) Using DI, you can then just set the controller's `retrievalThread` to a new instance of `MockRetrievalThread` within your test.

```
void "test getFiles"() {
    given:
    controller.retrievalThread = new MockRetrievalThread()

    when:
    params.id = 1
    def returnedFiles = controller.getFiles() 

    then:
    // assertions
}
```

2.b.) Or skip the MockRetrievalThread altogether and mock the `retrievalThread` bean using the `mockFor` method, and then set the mocked version to the injected instance in your controller.

```
void "test getFiles"() {
    given:
    def retrievalThreadMock = mockFor(RetrievalThread)
    retrievalThreadMock.demand.getFiles { Integer input -> 
        return ['file1', 'file2', 'etc.']
    }
    controller.retrievalThread = retrievalThreadMock.createMock()

    when:
    params.id = 1
    def returnedFiles = controller.getFiles() 

    then:
    // assertions
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use [integration testing](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.0.x/ref/Command%20Line/create-integration-test.html) instead to run the entire app, in order to avoid any beans not being injected.

```
grails create-integration-test org.bookstore.Book
```

Comment: that don't turn out to be a solution. Unit tests have their own importance that a unit alone is working perfectly or not. Integration tests are to make sure that those unit when talk to each other works well and no miscommunication is there.

Comment: I've answered the question..`Is there a way to clean this up or use something better than what I'm using?` ,no need to down-vote as my response provides an alternative way to run the test successfully ,while getting the grails bean, the integration is between the Tested object and another grails services\beans.